# Oracle SQL - Before-Insert Trigger not firing

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm new to Oracle SQL and today I wanted to try a sample trigger that does the same as the 'UNIQUE' statement. So the trigger should check before inserting if a specific attribute ('cityid') is already in the dataset.

The problem is that my trigger doesn't fire! Compilation works fine, but none of the commands are working.

Here is it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_cityid
BEFORE INSERT
    ON city
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF :old.cityid <> :new.cityid THEN
        insert into city (cityid, name, country, province, population, latitude, longitude) values (:new.cityid, :new.name, :new.country, :new.province, :new.population, :new.latitude, :new.longitude);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OK');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The attribute CITYID is already present!');
    END IF;

END;
/
```

And here is my table 'city' with NAME+COUNTRY+PROVINCE as primary key:

```
SQL> describe city;
 Name                                                  Null?    Typ
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- -------
 NAME                                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(35)
 COUNTRY                                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)
 PROVINCE                                              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)
 POPULATION                                                     NUMBER
 LONGITUDE                                                      NUMBER
 LATITUDE                                                       NUMBER
 CITYID                                                         NUMBER(38)
```

Btw, I know that the PK should refer to 'cityid', but this is just an exercise ...

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `:old.city_id` is always going to be null for an insert trigger; [the `old` pseudorecord is only populated for update and delete](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#CIHDBHIH). I think you're misunderstanding what `old` refers to, it isn't every existing row in the table. (But then, querying the table inside the trigger will get a mutating table error...). That doesn't mean it isn't firing. What do you see when you insert? Have you `set serveroutput on`, or your client's equivalent?

Comment: Also, a `before insert` fires **before** the insert, not **instead of** the insert.  So if your trigger worked it would be inserting a duplicate row when  `:old.cityid <> :new.cityid`.  Have a good read of the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/srvrside.htm#CNCPT88945

Comment: Ok, first of all Thank you. Secondly, I guess I need a INSTEAD-OF trigger? And I'm quering the old cityid for the comparison with: 'select cityid into cityid_old from city where cityid=:new.cityid;'

Comment: @MichaelGierer - `:old.city_id` does **not** give you the equivalent of that query though. And an `instead of` trigger applies to a view, not a table. You can raise an exception if your `before insert` trigger finds a problem that means the insert should *not* happen; otherwise it will just complete normally. But testing for an existing row is going to be a problem - for mutating table error, and for concurrency. I realise you're experimenting, but there's a reason this isn't done via a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an appropriate solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_cityid
BEFORE INSERT
    ON city
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    cityid_new city.cityid%TYPE := 0;
BEGIN

    select cityid into cityid_new from city where cityid = :new.cityid;

    IF cityid_new = :new.cityid THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'FEHLER: Diese CITYID ist bereits vorhanden!');
    END IF;

EXCEPTION

    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CITYID check OK.');
    END;

END;
/
```

If a row alreday exists, I correctly get the error -20001. And if there's no such CITYID, the trigger falls into the EXCEPTION, but does nothing.

Many thanks to all who helped me and for showing me the possibilites!

Comment: You don't need the `if` check; if the select doesn't get no-date-found then `cityid_new = :new.cityid` will always be true. But.... try to insert the same city ID from two different Oracle sessions - the trigger for each insert won't see the pending data for the other. Also try to insert two rows at once, in one statement.